# ? time delay, when using === or <=

Tags: verilog, hdl

When we use

```
input reg [7:0] ast, f_out;

ast === f_out ;

ast <= ast + 8'b00000001;
```

for those operations " === and <= ", **Have any time delay been occurred ?**

EDIT: I think something small like 1 unit time, am I wrong ?

used language : verilog

Comment: Is that the complete code sample? As presented it's not legal verilog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a simulation cycle delay if you use `<=` - ie a nonblocking assignment. Read up on blocking vs nonblocking assignments.

Also, `===` is not an assignment - its an equality operator that doesn't treat `x` and `z` as don't cares

Comment: Although this is overkill for a basic understanding, I'll note that nonblocking assignments do not involve the passage of simulation time unless there is a `#` delay control. The update of the LHS is placed on the NBA update queue for the current time slice; the NBA update queue is processed after all active events are completed.

Answer (score 1):

Time delays are most commonly specified using `#`.  Since I see no `#` in your code, there is probably no delay.

Another way to add delays is to use a `specify` block, and you don't show that either.  There are plenty of examples of specify in the Verilog IEEE Std.

You can check for delays yourself by running a simulation and printing time values:

```
$display($time);
```